# if and ifelse in R, multiple element used & nest failed

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I recently started with r, and I got problems with if and ifelse.

here is what I tried

```
two_d6 <- function(n)
{
  random_numbers <- matrix(
    sample(6, 2 * n, replace = T),
    nrow = 2
  )
  colSums(random_numbers)
}
```

this is a function to generate random numbers, no problem with it

```
scores <- two_d6(10)

for(i in 1:length(scores))
{ 
 
  if(scores[i] %in% c(2,3,12))
{
  game_statues <- F
  point <- NA
} else if(scores[i] %in% c(7,11))
{ 
  game_statues <- T
  point <- NA
} else
{
  game_statues <- NA
  point <- scores
}
}
game_table <- data.frame(game_statues = game_statues, point = point, 
                         score = scores) ; game_table


   game_statues point score
1            NA    10    10
2            NA     7     7
3            NA    10    10
4            NA     9     9
5            NA     7     7
6            NA     5     5
7            NA     5     5
8            NA    11    11
9            NA     7     7
10           NA     4     4
```

it doesn't work, seems only the final "else" part worked.

Then I tried:

```
ifelse(scores %in% c(2,3,12), ((game_statues <- F) & (point <- NA)), 
       ifelse(scores %in% c(7,11), ((game_statues <- T) & (point <- NA)),  
             ((game_statues <- NA ) & ( point <- scores))))

 [1]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA FALSE    NA    NA    NA    NA

game_table <- data.frame(game_statues = game_statues, point = point, 
                         score = scores) ; game_table

   game_statues point score
1            NA     8     8
2            NA     9     9
3            NA     7     7
4            NA     8     8
5            NA     6     6
6            NA     2     2
7            NA     8     8
8            NA    10    10
9            NA     7     7
10           NA     4     4
```

it seems the same reason with if function.

I can't see what's wrong. Could you please tell me how to improve it with these two functions and get the right table? THX!

Comment: `for (i in 1 : length(vec)) … vec[i] …` should almost always be written as `for (x in vec) … x …`.

Comment: You assign the whole vector `game_statues <- NA` and `point <- scores`. Since you are inside a `for`-loop, you probably wanted something like `point[i] <- scores[i]`?

Comment: @Martin Gal thank you, Martin, it works well now!

Comment: @lily Take a look at Ronak Shahs answer. This should simplify your approach a lot. Don't forget to accept his answer, if it helped you. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` as -

```
game_statues <- ifelse(scores %in% c(2,3,12), FALSE, 
                  ifelse(scores %in% c(7,11), TRUE, NA))

point <- scores
point[!is.na(game_statues)] <- NA
game_table <- data.frame(game_statues, point, scores) 
game_table

#   game_statues point scores
#1            NA     5     5
#2         FALSE    NA     2
#3            NA     8     8
#4            NA     4     4
#5          TRUE    NA     7
#6          TRUE    NA     7
#7          TRUE    NA     7
#8            NA     8     8
#9            NA     6     6
#10           NA     6     6
```